# Windows Batch File to delete all but a few folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a .bat script to delete all folders but roughly five pre-set ones. What I've done is make a for loop that addresses every folder, then the forloop checks through an IF statement if the folder's name matches a string, in which case it uses GOTO to go to the line below the RD command, so that the removing is skipped.

However, this ends the for loop, meaning every folder until the first exception gets deleted.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want, or are there tweaks on my script?

```
@echo off
echo Starting...
for /d %%i in ("C:\demo\*") do (
    if "%%i" == "C:\demo\mark" goto skipdel
    if "%%i" == "C:\demo\pjotr" goto skipdel
    if "%%i" == "C:\demo\jasper" goto skipdel
    rd /s /q %%i
    echo Deleted
    :skipdel
)
echo Done.
pause
```

Comment: goto breaks the FOR context.

Comment: and don't forget that this could not work in system files where path have spaces... if you have path like: "C:/Program Files (86x)/..." you must rather use: for /d %%i in ('type "C:\demo\*"') do (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested

```
@echo off
echo Starting...
for /d %%i in ("C:\demo\*") do (
    if not "%%i" == "C:\demo\mark" if not "%%i" == "C:\demo\pjotr"  if not "%%i" == "C:\demo\jasper" (
      rd /s /q %%i
      echo Deleted
    )

)
```

the goto exists the for command. You can emulate AND condition in bat with consecutive IFs. You can also iterate through the folders you want to skip with a one more internal FOR loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression and its combination with '|' option to find folders and delete the contents. 
using this approach you just have to add/remove string in regular expression part [0-9a-z]  without much problem in future for Ex use regular expression  **[mark|pjotr|jasper].**

Below is the approach -

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir "c:\demo" /b /ad ^| findstr /i "^[0-9a-z][^/]*$"' ) DO ( 

REM Efficeint way to delete files and folder. Remove nul if you want verbose output

del /f/s/q "c:\demo\%%G\*.*" > nul
rmdir /s/q "c:\demo\%%G"  > nul

)
```